QR Decomposition properties for generalized distributions
Let $\mathbf{H}$ be a complex-valued matrix, where the magnitudes of its entries are distributed according to a generalized distribution, such as the $\mathbf{\alpha-\mu}$ distribution where its probability density fonction (PDF) is given by $f_{Z}(x)=\frac{\alpha \mu^\mu x^{\alpha \mu-1}}{\hat{Z}^{\alpha \mu} \Gamma(\mu)}  e^{- \mu \frac{x^\alpha}{\hat{Z}^\alpha}},\quad x \geq 0, \, \alpha > 0, \, \mu > 0$, or a mixture distribution such as mixture gamma. I am interested in the following:
After performing a QR decomposition of $\mathbf{H}$, what is the distribution of the diagonal elements of the $\mathbf{R}$ matrix? what about the remaining elements in $\mathbf{R}$? I understand that when the entries of $\mathbf{H}$ are Rayleigh-distributed (complex Gaussian), the diagonal elements of $\mathbf{R}$ are chi-square distributed. Specifically, for a complex Gaussian matrix, the diagonal elements $\mathrm{R_{ii}}$ correspond to the norms of independent Gaussian vectors, and their squared magnitudes follow a chi-square distribution.
However, I am unsure how to extend this result to cases where the entries follow more complex distributions like alpha-mu or mixture Gamma. Any pointers how to proceed, theorems or techniques to use, or references would be greatly appreciated!
